# select option with data-native-menu="false"

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a select menu in jquery mobile. I have added `data-native-menu="false"` property to it so that I can stylize my own custom select menu.

I want to position the menu just below my select option. How can this be achieved.
Thnx

My code:

```
<select data-native-menu="false">
    <option>Sunday</option>
    <option>Monday</option>
    <option>Tuesday</option>
</select>
```

Comment: is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/8xusq/ if you like it i'll add it as an answer.

Comment: this is exactly wht I am looking for. Just one more thing. When you resize the window, even then the select menu's position should be the same. Currently in the fiddle if u change the sreen size, then the posirion of the menu changes.

Comment: You mean on orientation change? On mobiles an tablets window can't be resize, unless you want to use the code on desktop browser.

Comment: yes I want thr same position on orientation change.

Comment: And also, if I want to resize the browser window and still keep the position of menu same, can this be achieved ? Thanks

Comment: Ok, I'll update the code once I get back to office :)

Comment: if you want to customize the select option try to implement a class on it and customize with the help of css, define every element in a tree in the select options and implement your css...

Comment: @SaurabhLP I have already done all the css styling and its working perfectly fine. I had doubt regarding only the positioning of the menu. Styling is not an issue here.

Comment: test this one on your devices (desktop and mobile/tablet) http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Y7mym/ and let me know if it works well.

Comment: @Omar I tested it on the desktop but still the menu is changing position.

Comment: Yea i know, I'm not sure what's causing this. Sorry i couldn't help :)

Comment: @Omar thanks a lot :) atleast your solution gave me a direction to think !!

Comment: jqm is tricky some times :)